# How to disable Eclipse module-info popup?

Tags: java, eclipse, popup, disable

In Eclipse 2019-12 every time new Java project is created a popup pops up asking to create a module-info.java file. Without any discussion as to why this modile-info file is good or bad, is there a way to permanently disable this popup (without clicking the Next button and unchecking the module-info.java checkbox, which introduces even more clicks than permanent clicking Cancel on this popup)? This is a productivity question. As an educator, I create lots of projects as examples for various things and this popup keeps annoying me.

Answer (score 0):

Choosing Java 1.8 compliance disables the module-info.java checkbox on the second page of the new Java project, thus the module-info question doesn't pop up. But this is more of a workaround, not a solution, and can't help if newer compliance is needed.